# Create an array of objects by capturing a data attribute

Tags: jquery, arrays, collections

I have made a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Zfaf6/

I am experiementing with arrays, but only seem to output the first object.

Can any please advise, thanks.

**My jquery**

```
$("a.download-all").on('click', function () {

    var downloads = $('a[data-download]').attr('data-download');

    // This is the example output of the data in the variable...

    $('#varObj').html(downloads);

});
```

**My script**

```
<div id="images">

    <a href="#" data-download="http://image.com/1.jpg"><img src="images/x.gif" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#" data-download="http://image.com/2.jpg"><img src="images/x.gif" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-download="http://image.com/3.jpg"><img src="images/x.gif" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#" data-download="http://image.com/4.jpg"><img src="images/x.gif" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-download="http://image.com/5.jpg"><img src="images/x.gif" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#" data-download="http://image.com/6.jpg"><img src="images/x.gif" alt="" /></a>

<div>

<p><a href="#" class="download-all">Download all images</a></p>

<p id="varObj"></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zfaf6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `attr()` will, as a "getter" ([and per the docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr)) return the value of the *first* element matched; which is why you're only seeing one.

Either iterate over the match objects using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each), or use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map);

```
$("a.download-all").on('click', function () {

    var downloads = $('a[data-download]').map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('data-download');
    });

    // This is the example output of the data in the variable...
    $('#varObj').html(downloads.get().join(' '));
});
```

Comment: I think the map() is suited perfectly for this situation.

Comment: Good up! Can't believe I didn't think of map.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zfaf6/2/)**</kbd>

```
var downloads = [] ;

$("a.download-all").on('click', function () {

    $('a[data-download]').each(function(){   
        downloads.push( $(this).attr('data-download') );        
    });

    $('#varObj').html(downloads);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

calling attr() of a set will only return the first attr(). Also, use `data()` as it's easier to read.

So, the code just creates an empty array, then using `each` we push each item's `download` value into the array. The rest of your code is the same.

```
$("a.download-all").on('click', function () 
{
    var downloads = [];

    $('a[data-download]').each(function()
    {
        downloads.push( $(this).data('download') );
    });

    // This is the example output of the data in the variable...

    $('#varObj').html(downloads);
});
```

Comment: Thanks also. And the tip on data, always forget about that.

Comment: and the updating my title :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var downloads = $('a[data-download]').map(function(){   
   return  $(this).data('download');        
});
$("#varObj").html(downloads.join("-"));
```

Comment: You've trimmed my favourite answer down even more!

Comment: Though its a bit weird - not working for some reason... http://jsfiddle.net/Zfaf6/4/

Comment: typo : `download') )` extra bracket